# map array of object inside an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx, chakra-ui

I have this array of objects, that I've mapped through it to get its content as

```
const teamSliderContent = [
    {
        Describtion1: 'Chef. Mordy Wenk',
        Title: 'Head of the Chief staff.',
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        Describtion1: 'Chef. Mark Brunnett',
        Title: 'Junior chef.',
        id: 2,
    },
    {
        Describtion1: 'Chef. Griffin Zach',
        Title: 'a Talented Chef.',
        id: 3,
    },
    {
        Describtion1: 'Chef. Will Smith',
        Title: 'a Talented Chef.',
        id: 4,
    },
];
```

and this is how I mapped it:

```
{teamSliderContent.map(item => (
   <p>{item}</p>
))}
```

and I want to map this array of objects inside the previous array

```
const pizzaSlicesContent = [
    {
        sliceUp:
            'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86873404/169595266-b0085f5c-cdd9-4f96-93b0-49edcc08fa72.png',
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        sliceLeft:
            'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86873404/169595240-fe7f4c80-c8c3-44f6-9cc8-4fec55587f87.png',
        id: 2,
    },
    {
        sliceDown:
            'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86873404/169595250-a5692462-8aec-43f8-91a8-a042d9dd35db.png',
        id: 3,
    },
    {
        sliceRight:
            'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86873404/169595259-e8cc76a8-437c-4260-9d53-aaefd606173b.png',
        id: 4,
    },
];
```

what I mean is I need to get the second array to appear in every object of the first array I tried to do this `{pizzaSlicesContent.map(item2 => ( ))}` inside the first map , but it gave me an error

Comment: What do you mean: map this array of object inside the previous array. What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: what I mean is I need to get the second array to appear in every object of the first array 
I tried to do this 
{pizzaSlicesContent.map(item2 => (
                            
                        ))}
inside the first map , but it gave me an error

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your clarification, the intended output, and what error it was that you received. A [mre] would be nice as well. See [ask] for more tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `array.find` inside the `map` ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-euler-hhos9q?file=/src/App.js:1270-1530)) -

```
{teamSliderContent.map((item) => (
  <p key={item.id}>
    {item.Title}
    <img
      width={100}
      height={100}
      alt="pizza"
      src={
        pizzaSlicesContent.find((slice) => slice.id === item.id)
          .sliceRight
      }
    />
  </p>
))}
```

The only problem is that the array `pizzaSlicesContent` has different property names, `sliceUp`, `sliceDown`, `sliceLeft` & `sliceRight`.

Comment: From a comment by the OP: "what I mean is I need to get the second array to appear in every object of the first array".

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator in JavaScript.

```
let newArray = teamSliderContent.map((teamSlider) => {
  return ({
    ...teamSlider,
    pizzaSlicesContent: pizzaSlicesContent
  })
})
```

In the above code, using the spread operator on the `teamSlider` object, we're creating a new JavaScript object with all the properties of `teamSlider` object (shallow copy) and adds the `pizzaSlicesContent` into it.

Comment: Please explain the logic of the code you have shared.

Answer (score -1):

This function will do the trick:

```
/**
 * Zips and merges two object arrays
 * @param {Array<object>} a 
 * @param {Array<object>} b 
 * @returns 
 */
function mergeZip(a, b){
  return a.map((itemA, index) => ({...itemA, ...b[index]}))
}
```

What you want to do is [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (that's how the function built-in for this in Python is called) and at the same time merge the two objects within both arrays.

The easiest way to `zip()`, assuming both arrays have the same length, is to use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The callback of `map()` provides both the item within the array which is currently looped over as well as an index. Using that index you can get the value of the second array at the same position and then use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge the objects together.

Here the the function used for your usecase:

```js
const teamSliderContent = [
  {
    Describtion1: "Chef. Mordy Wenk",
    Title: "Head of the Chief staff.",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    Describtion1: "Chef. Mark Brunnett",
    Title: "Junior chef.",
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    Describtion1: "Chef. Griffin Zach",
    Title: "a Talented Chef.",
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    Describtion1: "Chef. Will Smith",
    Title: "a Talented Chef.",
    id: 4,
  },
];

const pizzaSlicesContent = [
  {
    sliceUp:
      "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86873404/169595266-b0085f5c-cdd9-4f96-93b0-49edcc08fa72.png",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    sliceLeft:
      "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86873404/169595240-fe7f4c80-c8c3-44f6-9cc8-4fec55587f87.png",
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    sliceDown:
      "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86873404/169595250-a5692462-8aec-43f8-91a8-a042d9dd35db.png",
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    sliceRight:
      "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86873404/169595259-e8cc76a8-437c-4260-9d53-aaefd606173b.png",
    id: 4,
  },
];

/**
 * Zips and merges two object arrays
 * @param {Array<object>} a 
 * @param {Array<object>} b 
 * @returns 
 */
function mergeZip(a, b){
  return a.map((itemA, index) => ({...itemA, ...b[index]}))
}

const result = mergeZip(teamSliderContent, pizzaSlicesContent)
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```